# physical dimensions and array dimensions

Tags: python, arrays

If I have a rainfall map which has three dimensions (latitude, longitude and rainfall value), if I put it in an array, do I need a 2D or 3D array? How would the array look like?

If I have a series of daily rainfall map which has four dimensions (lat, long, rainfall value and time), if I put it in an array, do I need a 3D or 4D array?

I am thinking that I would need a 2D and 3D arrays, respectively, because the latitude and longitude can be represented by a 1D array only (but reshaped such that it has more than 1 rows and columns). Enlighten me please.

Comment: It depends what you want to do with those data... You have to give a bit of context. But you should read about tidy data, long & wide format.

Comment: I only needed to do some basic operations like adding or averaging on those data. So the rainfall map basically would be a grid with rainfall values at a daily scale. I would use a series of these daily maps to get a monthly rainfall map or annual rainfall map or even an average daily rainfall map.

Comment: I would put the rainfall value as a value instead of a dimension. So, you would have 2D `array[lat][lon] = rainfall_value` or 3D `array[time][lat][lon] = rainfall_value` respectively.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense! I didn't realize that the value is not a dimension. Thanks a lot, I can sleep now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

I think that both propositions from @Genhis and @Bitzel are right depending on what you want to do...

If you want to be effective, I would recommend you to put both in 2D data structure and I would even advise you specifically to choose a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) which will put your data in some kind of matrix-like data structure but let you choose multiple indexes if you need to "think" in 3D or 4D.

It will especially be helpful with the 2nd kind of data you're mentioning "(lat, long, rainfall value and time)" as it is part of what is called "time series". Pandas has a lot of methods to help you averaging over some period of time (you can also group your data by longitude, latitude or location if needed).

On the contrary, if your objective is to *learn* about how to compute those numbers in Python, then you can use 2D arrays for the first case and 2D or 3D for the 2nd one as previous answers recommended. You could use something like numpy arrays as data structure instead of pure python list but that's debatable... 
One important point: *Choosing 3D arrays for the time series as @Genhis proposes would ask you to convert time in indexes* (through lookup tables or hash function) but that will require some more work...

As I said, you could also learn about tidy, [wide and long formats](https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/) if you want to learn more about those questions...

Answer (score 1):

for the rainfall map, the values you're describing are (latitude, longitude, rainfall value), you need to use a 2D array (matrix) since all you need is 3 columns and a number of rows. It will look like:

[rainfall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0dca.png)

For the values (lat, long, rainfall value, time) it's the same case. You need to use a 2D array with 4 columns and a number of rows:

[Rainfall matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G91rT.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the rainfall value shouldn't be a dimension. Therefore, you could use 2D `array[lat][lon] = rainfall_value` or 3D `array[time][lat][lon] = rainfall_value` respectively.

If you want to reduce number of dimensions further, you can combine latitude and longitude into one dimension as you suggested, which would make arrays 1D/2D.